# Can I trade the volume of a security or index?

Tags: exotics

Is it possible to trade a derivative product priced on the *volume* traded of some underlying security or index?

Does such a derivative exist on any exchange traded markets? Or anywhere?

Comment: I've never heard of a volume-linked instrument, but since volume and volatility are often related, you might be able to approximate what you want via a volatility-linked instrument.

Comment: I don't think there is one. First, it might be hard to define volume, especially for vehicles that can be traded outside of exchanges (e.g. equities). Another point is that you can directly influence the price by buying the underlying, and if you would like to hedge against it you even increase price by increasing volume. A proxy (but more long-term) can be shares of stock exchanges that profit when order volume goes up.

Comment: You can express views on volume indirectly through VWAP order types. You can pay 10-15 pips for a guaranteed vwap price and look to beat that through a hedge of your own if you believe you have a superior view on price levels and where volume trades. But this is more an expression of trading intraday volume.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the potential use cases for such a product?

Comment: @Atlas you could hedge against or go long takeovers without having to make a bet on the direction resulting from such action.

Comment: Or you could scrape tweets to speculate on market interest without having to gauge the direction of the sentiment...

Comment: But like chrisaycock said much of that could be achieved by trading volatility.

Comment: Don't think you'll get any decent pricing for this. Given the use case, best bet for that use case is var/ vol swaps as chrisaycock mentioned. Or you could try replicating payoffs with option strips.